# GMSServices GMSGeocoder reverseGeocodeCoordinate language of returned results in IOS

Tags: ios, google-maps

I have two applications which used in pair and both used GMSGeocoder from GMSServices for reverseGeocodeCoordinate search. But in first one results are coming in english, on other - in device local language. Device is **the same**.

I searched a lot, and found that now is no ways to make GMSGeocoder use specified language for result. It is impossible and we should use google API requests instead. But it works somehow, and i have no idea how to make second application return results in english language only.

Similar concerns mapView - different languages on the same device.

How to set english for GMSServices regardless device localization?

[image: Local device language present]
[image: No local languge present]

Comment: I dont think you can change the language for `GMSGeocoder`, but you can try to change the language for your app: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24333593/4195406

Comment: That the thing I was looking for. This code applied in fist application. Thank you a lot! You made my day.

Comment: Any side effects?

Comment: Ive used only english as app language, so didnt notice anything. (Cource, this dont means that them cant be there.)

Comment: I add an answer for this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22908370/gmsgeocoder-how-to-set-response-language/51015794#51015794) . It can solve this issue perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy paste answer from [stackoverflow.com/a/24333593/4195406](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24333593/4195406)

In `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

add

```
NSArray *languages = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    if (![[languages firstObject] isEqualToString:@"en"]) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@[@"en"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
```

This works for me

Answer (score 1):

GMSGeocoder sent you the county name, but not the country ISO code.

You can use native CLGeocoder class to get counytyISOcode from latitude and longitude. For example:

```
CLLocation *location = (your location)
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:
    ^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
        if ([placemarks count] > 0)
        {
            CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            NSLog(@"Your counry is %@",placemark. ISOcountryCode);
        }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to @Dren answer - it will help to add regionCode as well in the array

```
NSArray *languages = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    if (![[languages firstObject] isEqualToString:@"he"]) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@[@"he",@"he-IL"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
```