# How to set the language in GMSGeocoder Google Maps in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

How to change the result for the language set in Google Maps iOS Swift?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GMSServices GMSGeocoder reverseGeocodeCoordinate language of returned results in IOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31924147/gmsservices-gmsgeocoder-reversegeocodecoordinate-language-of-returned-results-in)